# How to remove a list item border in bootstrap list group?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just want to remove the first list-group-item top border:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item borderless">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>

.borderless li {
    border-top: none;
}
```

but doesn't work, Anybody can help me, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Problem:**

The current code you are trying is a descendant selector and will only work when `li` is the child of `.borderless` like below:

```
<div class="borderless">
  <li></li>
```

**Solution:**

Try the below multiple class selector which selects the list items which has a class `borderless`.

```
li.borderless { border-top: 0 none; }
```

---

**Output:**

```css
li.borderless {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item borderless">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 58):

In Bootstrap 4.0 you can simply set each individually or all using the border-* class.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item border-0">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-top-0">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-right-0">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-bottom-0">Four</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-left-0">Five</li>
<ul />
```

[Bootstrap 4.0 Borders Documententation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/)

Comment: Bootstrap 5 changed `border-left-0` and `border-right-0` to `border-start-0` and `border-end-0`.

Answer (score 8):

You can take advantage of the **:nth-child()** Selector, so you don't need to add the **borderless** class.

Example:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

The markup

```
.list-group li:nth-child(1){
  border-top: 0 none;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

You can remove borders by declaring border to none , in style element. Please see below

```
<h2>Basic List Group</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">Third item</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: this is not the bootstrap way to do so

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap class **.list-group-flush** may also be used to remove some of the borders.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#flush

Answer (score 2):

for Bootstrap 5 we can use the class **border-0** to remove borders in list-group-item,

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item border-0">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item border-0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item border-0">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item border-0">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item border-0">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `border-0` class to all `<li>` elements in your HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>5. First bootstrap page with layout</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-flex">
        <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
        <p>Resize this responsive paage to see th effect!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">
                        <p class="h3">CHARUSAT</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
  <ul *ngFor="let f of checkFields" class="list-group border-0">
    <li  class="list-group-item border-0"> {{f.title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Bootstrap 5 we can use the class "list-group-item-light" to remove borders in list-group-item,

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item-light">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item-light">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item-light">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item-light">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item-light">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```